# How to disable cache on logout in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3

I am using cakephp 2.3 version. I need to disable cache only when the user logs out. This is to prevent login in case the back button is pressed.

But for all other scenarios I don't want to disturb caching mechanism.

Right now i use the following function in AppController:

```
public function beforeRender() {
    $this->response->disableCache();
}
```

But I doubt that it disables the caching process completely. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe the user is automatically logged back into your site if they click on the back button after logging out. I'm guessing by your question that when the user does press the back button after logging out, you want them to be forwarded to the login page. Unfortunately, the browser may cache the last page it was on and give the user the illusion that they're still logged in. Rest assured that when they try and do something that requires them to be logged in, the session ID stored in the cookie, won't be recognized and they will  be forwarded to the authentication page.

One possible work around is to redirect the user to another controller action after the logout has taken place - this will introduce and additional transition in the browsers history. I don't know what will happen if they click back twice though.

Comment: I have same issue, User is not automatically logged back into site but after user logout and someone hit back button on browser, he can get previous user's data and that is not good

Comment: This is a browser caching issue, PHP physically isn't rendering the previous user's view of your website.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the header page of your application:

```
<?php
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");
?>
```