# cakephp session is not deleting without clearing cache

Tags: php, session, cakephp

Upon logout, my cakpphp session is not being deleted.In logout function I have also logged out the user from Facebook . After calling logout function it logs out user from Facebook but not from the website. To log out from site I have to click on logout button and then clear the cache (ctrk+r) to get the logout working.
Can anybody tell me where I am wrong.

```
function logout()
{
    $this->Session->delete("SESSION_USER");
    $this->Session->delete('logout'); 
    $this->redirect(BASE_URL);
}
```

Comment: `I have to click on logout button and then clear the [browser] cache` - you are looking at the wrong problem. The user _is_ logged out they are looking at a stale page because it's been served with cache headers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable cache on logout in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457261/how-to-disable-cache-on-logout-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
function logout() {
   $this->Session->destroy();
   $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

and add this (if not already added) in your `beforeFilter()` method::

```
$this->Auth->allow('logout');
```